# Combinatorial proof for two identities

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

- Does exist a combinatorial proof for the following two identities ?

  - $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}  \binom{x+k}{k} = \binom{x+n+1}{n}$
  - $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}  k\binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$

I know how to derive the identites from $(1+x)^n$ , but I am searching for a combinatorial proof ?

Comment: For what it's worth, there are several proofs of the second identity here: [How to prove this binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n {r {n \choose r}} = n2^{n-1}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/how-to-prove-this-binomial-identity-sum-r-0n-r-n-choose-r-n2n-1)

Comment: My solution is identical to acarchau's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second identity counts the number of nonempty sets with a distinguished representative; that is, all pairs $(x,S)$ such that $S \subseteq [n]$ with $x \in S$.

1. You can pick a set consisting of $k$ elements (in $\binom n k$ ways) and pick the representative in $k$ ways for each choice of the set.
2. You can pick the representative $x \in [n]$ first, and then choose the *other* members of the set in $2^{n-1}$ ways.

Equating these two counts, we are done.

Comment: is it an answer for a question where "a Combinatorial proof" is being requested - where I'm referring to a question saying: prove the following by a story

Answer (score 13):

For the first identity:

> $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}  \binom{x+k}{k} = \binom{x+n+1}{n}$

The left-hand side is the number of sequences of blue and yellow balls you can make such that there are exactly $x$ blue balls and at most $n$ yellow balls.

The right-hand side creates the same sequences by enumerating all sequences with $x+1$ blue balls and $n$ yellow balls, and then always removing the rightmost blue ball and all yellow balls to the right of it.

Comment: Nice. Actually, this same identity came up implicitly in a recent post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65947/combinatorics-number-of-permutations-of-m-as-and-at-most-n-bs/65966#65966 . (Well, I got the right hand side as the answer, and Thijs' answer gets the left hand side sum; so the two sides must match. :-))

Comment: And I used it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/why-does-this-expected-value-simplify-as-shown/65408#65408) a few days earlier, but couldn't think of anything but an appeal to Pascal's triangle then.

Answer (score 4):

You are choosing $n$ people from $x+n+1$ people who are lined up in a row. The right side counts the number of choices.

The left side counts the choices in another way. For any $k$ from $0$ to $n$, select *all* of the  first $n-k$ people (from the left), then *not* the next one, then choose $k$ people from the remaining $x+n+1-(n-k+1)$, that is from the remaining $x+k$.  There are $\binom{x+k}{k}$ ways to do this. The sum of the $\binom{x+k}{k}$ thus counts the choices of $n$ people from the $x+n+1$.