# Combinatorial proof to the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x+k}{k}=\binom{x+n+1}{n}$?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combinatorial proof for two identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67068/combinatorial-proof-for-two-identities)

The identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x+k}{k}=\binom{x+n+1}{n}
$$
can be verified by a straightforward induction, but is there some nice combinatorial argument  which proves it? Here $x$ is a nonnegative integer, by the way.

I've always found combinatorial arguments make it easier to remember such identities and intuitively grasp them so I would appreciate seeing one. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rewrite it as $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x+k}x=\binom{x+n+1}{x+1}\;.$$ The righthand side clearly counts the subsets of $[x+n+1]$ of size $x+1$. The lefthand side breaks that count down according to the largest element of the subset. That is, if the largest element is $x+k+1$, the other $x$ elements must be chosen from the set $[x+k]$, and this can be done in $\binom{x+k}x$ ways. (Here I use $[n]$ for $\{1,\dots,n\}$.)