# Combinatoric Proof of $\sum_0^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1} = \binom{n+k}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$\sum_0^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1} = \binom{n+k}{k}$

I think there are two different ways to prove the above identity: one is algebraic and the other one is combinatoric.

I have seen there's some ways to handle this problem with some sort of lattice like structure.

Any advice for approaching this problem in "combinatoric" way?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191548/combinatorial-proof-of-sum-k-0n-binomnk-1k-binom2nn?rq=1), and generalize the answer given there, i.e., consider $k$-element subsets of $\{1,...,n+k\}$, and partition the collection of all such subsets according to their largest element.

Comment: @Beverlie: Do you know $$x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n \\\to\left(\begin{array}{c}n+k-1\\ k-1\end{array}\right)$$ ?

Comment: Now I just know due to the help from Khosrotash

Comment: Isn't this, after some small transformations, the same sum as this: [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794)? You might find something useful also in [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1490794).

Comment: This does *not* seem to be a duplicate of the question cited since this question asks for a combinatorial argument.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_1,x_2,...\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$
and we need to answer numbers of solution of this nequality 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k\leq n$$ one method is partitioning ,so we have 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k\leq n  (\equiv)
\\\to\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k = 0 & \left(\begin{array}{c}0+k-1\\ k-1\end{array}\right)\\x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k = 1 & \left(\begin{array}{c}1+k-1\\ k-1\end{array}\right)\\x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k =2&\left(\begin{array}{c}2+k-1\\ k-1\end{array}\right)\\\vdots\\x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k = n& \left(\begin{array}{c}n+k-1\\ k-1\end{array}\right)\end{cases} $$sum of the is $$\sum_0^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1} $$ second method to find the number of solution is to add $\bf{x_{k+1}}$ as new variable ,and convert inequality to equation .
  so 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k \leq n  \space (\equiv)\\
x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_k +\color{red} {\bf{x_{k+1}}}=n \to \binom{n+(k+1-1}{(k+1)-1}$$ hence
$$\sum_0^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1} =\binom{n+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$$

Comment: (+1) Now that I've posted my answer, I see that it is essentially the same as yours, except with stars and bars rather than variables and values. If this is too close for your comfort, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial Approach**

The [Stars and Bars Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) says that there are $\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}$ ways to put $i$ stars into $k$ bins. Thus, there are
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}
$$
$$
\underbrace{\star\star\star\,\mid\,\star\,\mid\,\star\star}_\text{$i$ stars and $k-1$ bars}\qquad\underbrace{\star\star\star\star\star}_\text{$n-i$ stars}
$$
ways to put up to $n$ stars into $k$ bins. We can also count this same number by adding a bin to hold the excess $n-i$ stars and get that the number of ways to put the $n$ stars into the $k+1$ bins to be
$$
\binom{n+k}{k}
$$
$$
\underbrace{\star\star\star\,\mid\,\star\,\mid\,\star\star\,\mid\,\star\star\star\star\star}_\text{$n$ stars and $k$ bars}
$$

---

**Algebraic Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{k-1+i}{i}\binom{n-i}{n-i}\tag{1}\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{-k}{i}\binom{-1}{n-i}\tag{2}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{-k-1}{n}\tag{3}\\
&=\binom{k+n}{n}\tag{4}\\
&=\binom{k+n}{k}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ and $\binom{k}{k}=[k\ge0]$
$(2)$: convert to [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(4)$: convert from negative binomial coefficients
$(5)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$