# Prove the identity $ \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} i = n2^{n-1} $ using combinatorial proof.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Prove the identity $ \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} i = n2^{n-1} $ using combinatorial proof.

Comment: You are trying to explain this by  counting a given set in  two different ways, like one of the previous questions you posted  about $\binom{52}{13}$ and I answered?

Comment: That was a different question. I know it may seem the same, but that was actually asking to prove it with another identity; this question is asking for a proof which is using combinatorial methods.

Comment: You are not searching for popular questions (regarding these binomial identities) which have been adequately answered. If you have any specific query then post it, but your 3 questions on these identities are really duplicates.

Comment: I have looked at the other solutions posted to the same question. The reason why I posted this was to actually understand what 'counting arguments' means because none of the other questions explicitly said this.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/how-to-prove-this-binomial-identity-sum-r-0n-r-n-choose-r-n2n-1) and the [questions which are linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7757)? For example, [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67068). And [this questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388587/combinatorial-proof-of-sumn-i-1-binomnii-n2n-1) looks like direct duplicate. (And again, looking [at the linked questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/388587) might be useful, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the following  counting problem:

How many ways do you have of choosing a non-empty subset of $S_n:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and then an element of this subset?

You can choose a subset of $i$ elements in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways (note that $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}$ gives you all the subsets of $S_n$ that is $2^n$) then you pick one of the $i$ element of this subset in $i$ ways. Hence the total number is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} i,$$
that is the left-hand side of your identity.

What about the right-hand side?

Another approach: note that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} i=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i}\cdot {n-1 \choose i-1} i=n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n  {n-1 \choose i-1}=n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \cdot {n-1 \choose j}=n2^{n-1}.$$.

Answer (score 1):

$\binom ni$ is the number of ways to pick $i$ items out of $n$, and in your sum there is an extra factor $i$. So we can count all the ways to draw $i$ items and paint one of them red. This is the same as painting one item red and picking $i-1$ white ones in all possible ways.

Comment: Would this be considered 'counting arguments'?

Comment: I don't see a better way to describe it than as a "counting argument". Unless you would prefer "paint shop" ?