# Combinatorial Analysis: Fermat's Combinatorial Identity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was looking through practice questions and need some guidance/assistance in Fermat's combinatorial identity. I read through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497413/fermats-combinatorial-identity-how-to-prove-combinatorially) on the stack exchange, but the question was modified in the latest edition of my book.

The book asks for a combinatorial argument (no computations needed) to establish the identity:

$${n \choose k} = \sum_{i=k}^n {i-1 \choose k-1}   \text{ where }n\ge k$$

Hint given: Consider set of numbers $1$ through $n$, and how many subsets of size $k$ have $i$ as their highest numbered member?

I'm still getting a grasp on the way these arguments work, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the first part to get you started. Fix $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.  To choose a subset of size $k$ with largest element $i$, we choose $i$, and then we must choose the remaining $k-1$ elements from $\{1, 2, \ldots, i-1\}$.  (If we choose an element in the range $\{i+1, i+2, \ldots, n\}$, then $i$ won't be the largest element!)

Can you see where the summation comes from?  What are the possible values for the largest element of a $k$-element subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$?

*Edit.* Editing in my comment from below:

We are going to count the number of $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, of which there are $\binom{n}{k}$, ordering them by their largest element. To choose a subset of size $k$ with largest element $i$, we choose $i$, and then we must choose the remaining $k-1$ elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,i−1\}$, which yields $\binom{i-1}{k-1}$ possibilities. Since this is a $k$-element subset, the largest element $i$ must be in the range $\{k,k+1,\ldots,n\}$, so we sum over this range.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot actually.
By picking one number smaller at a time, it covers the whole summation, and thus gives me the total n choose k (whatever k is defined as). Thank you for the insight. (I think that's what you were getting at).  //side note: I would upvote, but lack the "rep", but will return when I can

Comment: I honestly don't see this pattern

Comment: We are going to count the number of $k$-element subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, of which there are $\binom{n}{k}$, in order of their largest element.  To choose a subset of size $k$ with largest element $i$, we choose $i$, and then we must choose the remaining $k−1$ elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,i−1\}$, which yields $\binom{i-1}{k-1}$ possibilities.  Since this is a $k$-element subset, the largest element $i$ must be in the range $\{k, k+1, \ldots, n\}$, so we sum over this range.

Comment: @Quasicoherent why would we need those largest elements?

Comment: @parvin I don't understand your question.  Could you clarify?  Every subset has a largest element, and we are simply organizing our counting by grouping together those subsets with the same largest element.

Comment: I see, you mean you consider one indivisual which is the largest, each time, then calculation the rest's combinations? so every element would be the biggest for one time ?

Comment: @parvin Yes, I think that's right.  You could try computing an example, e.g., enumerating all subsets of $3$ elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to try it out.

Comment: I understand this but why are we summing over all the values and how does this help us establish equality?

Comment: @user1234 Did you read my [comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935872/combinatorial-analysis-fermats-combinatorial-identity/935901?noredirect=1#comment3366622_935901)? I've edited it into the answer now. I think this answers your question.